# Can't login Visual Studio Community Edition 2015

Tags: json, authentication, windows-10, visual-studio-2015

I'm using the free version of Visual Studio. After 30 days I need to login to be able to keep using the software. When I want to login I get the following error:

```
"Void Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonDictionaryContract.set_PropertyNameResolver(System.Func`2<System.String,System.String>)"
```

**Things I allready tried:**

- Reinstalling Visual Studio and checking the hash of the installation medium
- Downloading the newest version of the newtonsoft.net
- Registering the newest version of Json with GAC
- Rebooted computer

I'm running a authenticated en fully updated version of Windows 10 Home Edition.

Help with logging in is greatly appreciated

Comment: look at this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsvc/2015/05/18/login-problem-with-visual-studio-2013-due-to-issues-with-json-dll/